# Calculate the Taylor series of $f(x) =\ln( 1 -x +x^2) $ and the domain of convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I just stuck at the following exercise:

Show that the function f has a Taylor series and calculate it, with $x_0 = 0$.
$$ f(x) = \ln{(1-x+x^2)}$$
Because I already know the Taylor series from 
$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^n \cdot\frac{(x-0)^n}{n}} $$ 
I tried to substitute but surrendered short after the usage of binomial theorem, because I was unable to reorder the sum again.
Also with the 'classic' way, going through the first n derivatives I cannot come to a solution ([Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+ln%281-x%2Bx%5E2%29) told me one ofc, but I'm unable to reach it)

Any hint(s) and/or solution(s) are welcome :)

Comment: $1 - x + x^2 = \frac{1+x^3}{1+x}$

Comment: Because I don't see the improvement in the substitution, I'll try to deriavte it :D

Comment: You may also want to use the fact that $\ln\frac{a}{b} = \ln a - \ln b$ for $a,b>0$. (These two facts, the one above and this, combined with the Taylor series for $\ln(1+y)$.

Comment: Yeah, I got the solution ... How I close the question/mark a answer as right now ? :S

Comment: I suppose a way (the best?) would be for @DanielFischer to post his comment as an answer, so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution comes from recognising

$$1-x+x^2 = \frac{1+x^3}{1+x}.$$

With that, we obtain $\ln (1-x+x^2) = \ln (1+x^3) - \ln (1+x)$, and from the Taylor series of $\ln (1+x)$, the Taylor series of $\ln (1+x^3)$ is obtained by replacing $x$ with $x^3$. So we have

\begin{align}
\ln (1-x+x^2) &= \ln (1+x^3) - \ln (1+x)\\
&= \Biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{3n}}{n}\Biggr) - \Biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}\Biggr)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n
\end{align}

where

$$a_n = \begin{cases} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} &, n \not\equiv 0 \pmod{3}\\ \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}2}{n} &, n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}. \end{cases}$$

Slightly slower, but not reliant on spotting the trick is a factorisation of the argument of the logarithm,

$$1-x+x^2 = (1-\alpha x)\biggl(1-\frac{1}{\alpha}x\biggr),$$

where $\alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha} = 1$, so $\alpha = e^{\pm i\pi/3}$. From that we obtain

$$\ln (1-x+x^2) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha^n + \alpha^{-n}) \frac{x^n}{n}.$$

It is not immediately obvious that these two series are identical, but can be verified without too much difficulty.